# Does my ML program output, after the model is done, keeps learning from the input I give him?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm starting to explore the world of ML.NET with C# and this question came up in my mind. When I input a sentence in the console and it gives me the result (all this in the program after the model), does the ML keeps learning? And is there any way to tell the machine if its predictions are right or wrong so it learns better?

Answer (score 1):

Once you build a model in ML.NET and use it to create a prediction engine for predictions, there is no more training at that point. You would either need to train the model again from scratch or retrain the same model again on new data, if the performance of it isn't good.

To find if the predictions are correct, you would [evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/train-machine-learning-model-ml-net#evaluate-model-quality) the model on test data. That will give you metrics that you can use to determine how well the model performs on data it hasn't seen before.